# How to count amounts of dates by quarter and year in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet and I want to count a column of dates by quarter and year. As example: find out how many dates that are in second quarter of 2015.

However, it seems like Google Sheets get problems when i try to count a range of dates.

I can do this:

```
=COUNTIFS(ROUNDUP(MONTH('sheet-label'!B2)/3),1)
```

But not this:

```
=COUNTIFS(ROUNDUP(MONTH('sheet-label'!B1:B50)/3),1)
```

I now tried to build a custom function to do the job (Go to "Tools -> Script editor" to add custom functions in Google Sheets). I tried to make the function under. However it's still not able to count correctly, but I don't get any errors.

Any leads what I'm doing wrong or other possible solutions?

```
function countQuarterByYear(date, quarter, year) {

  var counter = 0;
  var arrayLength = date.length;
  var dateYear;
  var dateQuarter;
  var dateTemp;

  for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

    dateTemp = date[i];

    dateYear = dateTemp.getYear;

    dateQuarter = dateTemp.getMonth;
    dateQuarter = Math.ceil(dateQuarter/3);


    if ((dateYear == year) && (dateQuarter == quarter)){
   counter++;
  }

  }
  return counter;

}

function test() {
  countQuarterByYear(["2/7/2016", "8/5/2015"], 2, 2015);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using sumproduct:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(1*(YEAR('sheet-label'!B1:B50)=2015)*(ROUNDUP(MONTH('sheet-label'!B1:B50)/3,0)=2)))
```

The * between year and month is 'and'.